# Filtering rows based on multiple column value combinations pandas

Tags: python, pandas, filtering

I am currently investigating flight data. In order to simplify my huge dataset I want to filter every unique combination of origin airport and destination airport.

```
connections = flights[["ORIGIN_AIRPORT", "DESTINATION_AIRPORT"]].value_counts()
```

However, if I do so, there still do remain doubled pairs where just the origin and destination airport is swapped ( for me: SFO -> LAX and LAX -> SFO is the same). Hoq can I filter out those doubles?

[image]
Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Can you try `dataframe.apply(sorted, axis=1).drop_duplicates()`?

Comment: Well, thats exactly what I am looking for: In my case theres an error message (TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str')

Comment: Have you tried it without keeping the third column with numbers?

Answer (score 1):

The `(TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'` error happens because the `sort` tries to sort by all the columns. The solution is to specify the columns you want to filter by:

```py
connections = flights[['ORIGIN_AIRPORT', 'DESTINATION_AIRPORT']].apply(sorted, axis=1).drop_duplicates()
```

Result:

```
0    [LAX, SFO]
2    [JFK, LAX]
4    [LAS, LAX]
5    [LGA, ORD]
dtype: object
```